# How to Set Rectangle location properties? (Old Way)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

Oh yes, I saw this = msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Dim recta As New Rectangle
```

It says these properties are Read-only.

```
recta.Left =  
recta.Bottom =  
recta.Right =  
recta.Top =
```

And my problem is, I want to use these properties to set values :-/
Because i have values in this format. Many!
And so i guess, i am in a problem. ^_^

I saw the example..

```
Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 5)  
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 10, 10, 100, 50)
```

How do i..?

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(left-x, bottom-y, right-x, top-y)
```

Instead of..

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 10, 10, 100, 50)
```

OR

Is there anyway to convert locations?
E.G 1) 2694 to 9    'A Y co-ordinate
2) 2706 to 12   'A height

Because i want only the 'Y' and 'Height' converted.

[image]

Comment: I know that but how do you create one with location like this (0,2694,27,2706) ?

Comment: The code you want to write should work *if* you give it a Pen.

Comment: Your question is actually how to convert the input text values for Y and Height correctly. I am afraid no one here can answer your question. You need to check how these values are generated and to try to parse them back. For example in the text file for char W Y is 2694 and value in the table is 9; for char a Y is again 2694 and the table value is 10. If you can tell us what is the logic of this probably someone could help you.